# How to migrate all of the WordPress content from one host to another?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache2

I'm about to export all of my existing WordPress content from one server into another for backup and recovery purpose, how can I do this?

is it through the MySQL side or can be done through web administration console eg. wp-admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this on the console

SQL:
mysqldump --all-databases -u MYSQL_USER -pMYSQL_PASS > A_FILE_TO_DUMP.sql

files:
tar -cvzf www.tar.gz /var/www

The I move them using scp and reverse the procedure

Comment: thanks man, is there anything that you need to change first before you import it ? to avoid cross update problem ?

Comment: You have to put your files in the same path as on the old server (proabably /var/www), otherwise you should change the wordpress's path param from the mysql.

Answer (score 2):

you can take the database backup form the `phpmyadmin, cpanel`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database

and additionally there are wordpress plugin that can take backup of your database for you

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-db-backup/

Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget you'll also need to back up and restore any uploaded files (pictures, etc.) if you go down this route; they're not stored in the database. Personally I pay the monthly charge for [VaultPress](http://vaultpress.com) to handle this stuff for me...